# Images not loading in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a strange issue in my wordpress website. previously images are not loading automatically on website. but when I activated firebug all images loads in a flash. However this issue is resolved now but websites seems to be very slow it takes 2 minutes to load images. I am facing this issue after moving website on go daddy hosting.

Here is the link of the website that is hosted on godady
 http://www.mobilemag.in

And my old server url is  http://148.251.158.133/mobilemag-old/

Please can any one check and guide me how to optimize this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Images are not getting resolved in your new website . All the URLs are coming like this:

```
http://http//mobilemag.in//wp-content/uploads/2009/05/image_5413_largeimagefile-150x150.jpg
```

Please change Media URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload DB again with ***[wp migrate db](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)***

Following are some steps :

**STEP 1** : Install wp migrate db in your local site then after activate plugin go to tools and select **Migrate DB**

[image]

**STEP 2** : Set your link as per your choice.

[image]

**STEP 3**  : After saving database(after click on migrate button you will get database in zip) just upload in live website.

Answer (score 0):

i have checked your site and found that you have the problem with the image path :

`http://http//mobilemag.in//wp-content/uploads/2015/05/2014_bugatti_veyron_ettore_bugatti_legend_edition-1440x900-1.jpg` (your current path which i have fetch from firebug)

it should be like : `http://mobilemag.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/2014_bugatti_veyron_ettore_bugatti_legend_edition-1440x900-1.jpg`

so do not pass the static path here.  write me the code how you display the images there i will correct it out.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is You have to update your database.

Steps:

1.download sql of your database.

2.Open with notepad++

3.Copy----//http//mobilemag.in//wp-content  and find in the sql

4.Repace all with----/mobilemag.in/wp-content

this will obviously work for correct path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one for your help. I have corrected the media path but the issue is still there. Images takes long time to load. All content is loaded in no time but images takes more then 2 minutes to load.

Thanks